# How to study the impact of NUMA in Java algorithms

Tags: java, performance, affinity, numa, numactl

I'm studying some codes in Java (*SOR algorithm and LU factorisation*). The main goal is to study the impact of executing such algorithms in a NUMA aware architecture. I already found some tools such as *numactl*, and other affinity environment variables. Such as: **GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY (GCC)** and **KMP_AFFINITY (ICC)** to pin threads to cores using the same algorithms in C. However I don't know what alternatives I have for studying NUMA in Java. For Java I only use *numactl* with performance gains using **--interleave=all** flag but I don't really have control about what is happening in a JVM level.

I found another tool called *numastat* which is supposed to measure "NUMA counters" in a NUMA architecture and know the allocations which were "hit" (numa_hit) and "miss" (numa_miss) in a NUMA-Node. However I'm not sure how can I use it to measure this counters with my Java application.
What kind of tests (and programming techniques) should I perform in order to study the impact of NUMA in Java applications?

Thanks for your help.